# Lambda not returning array but displaying in Console.Log

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

Another Lambda question - managed to sort my previous issue but I'm having a different issue this time. The issue I am having is I have a function which retrieves some data from a database. I want to push this data to an Array and return that Array from this lambda so I can do further work with it elsewhere i.e. filtering and so on. Here is my code:

```
  var responses = [];

exports.handler = functions.https.onRequest(() => {  
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      responses.push({
        date: childSnapshot.val().Date,
        name:childSnapshot.val().name,
        response: childSnapshot.val().response
      })
    });
    admin.app().delete().then(() => {})
    console.log(responses);
  })    
  return responses;
})
```

Now when I test this in the Lambda console it returns null, but the `console.log(responses)` works fine and prints out the data. This is a picture of the output I am seeing. 
 [Link to the output from the lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ4yz.png)

What I want is the function to return the Array, would appreciate any help in doing so.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It also looks like you are returning `response` from the on "value" handler, not from the actual exported Lambda function event handler.

Comment: Sorry @jarmod had the wrong version up but have edited to the correct version now.

Comment: You haven't indicated what `functions.https.onRequest()` is or what `ref` is, but if you `console.log(responses)` immediately before `return responses;` does your Lambda function return *before* any values are pushed to the `responses` array? I'd expect to see empty array rather than null returned, however. It's going to be hard to correct the code without knowing more about `functions.https.onRequest()` and `ref`.

Comment: Ok so the database I am pulling from is a firebase realtime database. 'Functions.https.onRequest' is how retrieving data functions are written with firebase. ref is a pointer to the database table itself, in this case the table is called responses so ref points to database().ref('responses'). I took the console.log(responses) recommendation and it isnt returning anything but an empty array so it looks like the array isnt being populated. I find that weird as it is being populated in the function above.

Comment: This is standard JavaScript asynchronous behavior. The on "value" event handler is called *after* the Lambda function has completed, because you aren't handling the async part correctly. That said, `Functions.https.onRequest` is how you create a function that handles HTTP events. Lambda functions aren't HTTP event handlers. Do you know for sure that using this style of code will work with AWS Lambda? An AWS Lambda event handler takes event, context, and callback as parameters.